# Concatenate multiple values to a single column using stuff() in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string-aggregation

```
ID  | NAME  
----|--------  
1   |Ann  
2   |Jake  
1   |Julie  
3   |Paul  
2   |Shane  
4   |Kumi
```

I want to concatenate values using `stuff()` as below. And the single values should not be affected by the `stuff()` function.

```
ID  | NAME  
----|--------  
1   |Ann,Julie  
2   |Jake,Shane  
3   |Paul  
4   |Kumi
```

How to do that?

Comment: please also add what have you tried and the issue you are facing

Comment: Did you google it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #A VALUES
(1,'ANN'),
(2,'JAKE'),
(1,'JULIE'),
(3,'PAUL'),
(2,'SHANE'),
(4,'KUMI')

SELECT DISTINCT ID ,
STUFF((SELECT ','+NAME
FROM #A T1
WHERE T1.ID=T2.ID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') FROM #A T2
```

Answer (score 0):

STUFF doesn't do concatenation,Its for XML which does this.Stuff only replaces values as per choice

```
select id,
stuff((select ','+name from #t1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from #t1 t1
group by  id
```